# Bash Script Version Updating from a Web Server

Tags: bash, sh

I am trying to automate script updating over www. Not sure if this is the best way of doing it?

```
# Check for Latest Version, Download Latest If CurrentVersion is not equal to the latest version

CurrentVersion=10.1.1

LatestVersion=$(curl http://www.some-url.com/version.txt)


if [[ $CurrentVersion = $LatestVersion ]]; then echo "Latest Version is Already Installed"; 


else curl --url http://www.some-url.com/download --output ~/Scripts/;


    echo "script is now updated !" 

fi
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply create a cron task that executes the following script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh

url="http://www.some-url.com/download"
file="${HOME}/Scripts/Backups/Daily/download"

curl -z "$file" -f "$url" -O "$file"
```

Using option `-z` will make curl check whether the file in the URL has a newer timestamp than the local file. If so, it will update the local file.